# Are there any Eushully games that cover the God's War?

Tags: kamidori-alchemy-meister

In the info section to *Kamidori Alchemy Meister*, it talks about how there was a war between the Ancient Gods, the Modern Gods and the Mechanical Gods in which the Mechanical Gods were destroyed, the Ancient Gods were just defeated and the Modern Gods won and became the ones that were to be worshiped.

I know the *Battle Goddess* series has something to do with one of the Gods (a Goddess) who chooses a champion, but as she becomes more powerful she begins to take over his body, and because of this he starts to transform into a girl. However, I'm not sure if the *Battle Goddess* series has anything to do with this war (only one character makes a cameo appearance in *Kamidori* if you use your New Game + Data to access the bonus quests and events).

So I am wondering: are there any Eushully games that take place during this war between the 3 groups of gods?